# dict values pass into a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have below dictionary

```
a={
'set1': {'fileName': 'filename1', 
'moduleName': 'modulename1',  
'connection1.name': 'connection1', 
'connection.test':'connectiontest1',
'connection2.name': 'connection2', 
'connection.test':'connectiontest2',
'queue1.name': 'queue1',
'queue1.test':'queuetest1',
'topic1.name':'topic1',
'topic1.test':'topic1test',
'topic2.name':'topic2',
'topic2.test':'topic2test',
'ServerName': 'serverone', 
'DeploymentName': 'deployment1'
},

'set2':{'fileName': 'filename2', 
'moduleName': 'modulename2',  
'connection1.name': 'connection1', 
'connection.test':'connectiontest1',
'queue1.name': 'queue1',
'queue1.test':'queuetest1',
'topic1.name':'topic1',
'topic1.test':'topic1test',
'topic2.name':'topic2',
'topic2.test':'topic2test',
'ServerName': 'servertwo', 
'DeploymentName': 'deployment2'
}}
```

in each set, I need to pass it to a function to create a server from the above dictionary.

```
def create_server_config(fileName,moduleName,connection,connectiontest,topic,topictest,queue,queuetest,servername,deploymentname):

    create_queue(queue,queuetest)

    create_topic(topic,topictest)

    create_connection(connection,connectiontest)
```

In this I want to pass each set into a function as an argument So that it will create a server for each set, the problem here is queue,topic,connection has multiple increment values in each set. so anyone helps me with how to pass it to a function. for example, if I want to create a queue then under create_server_config function , need to pass all the queue and queuetest related to set1 dict.

Comment: in Set1, your dictionary has `'connection.test':'connectiontest1'` and `'connection.test':'connectiontest2'`. This cannot be possible. Is it `'connection.test1':` and `'connection.test2':`

Comment: Also, will `'connection1.name'`, `'queue1.name'`, and `'topic1.name'` always exist in a set? And if `'topic2.name'` exists but `'connection2.name'` and `'queue2.name'` does not exist, what parameters are to be passed to create the server? values from 1?

Answer (score 0):

I have a few questions for you. Based on that, the answer might change.

Below code assumes the following:

1. In Set1 & Set2, there are two `connection.test` keys. This may be a typo. I am assuming the first one is `connection1.test` and second one is `connection2.test`
2. connection1.name, queue1.name, and topic1.name will ALWAYS be present in each set
3. If topic2.name exists but connection2.name and queue2.name does not exist, then it is OK to pass connection1.name and queue1.name values to create server config.
4. Similarly, if any combination of `connection2.name`, `connection2.test`, `queue2.name`, `queue2.test`, `topic2.name`, `topic2.test` exists but the others do not exist, then the value from `xxx1.name` or `xxx1.test` will be used in its place where xxx is connection or queue or topic.

This code will call the create server config function for each value of the dict:

```
a={
    'set1':{'fileName': 'filename1', 
            'moduleName': 'modulename1',  
            'connection1.name': 'connection1', 
            'connection1.test':'connectiontest1',
            'connection2.name': 'connection2', 
            'connection2.test':'connectiontest2',
            'queue1.name': 'queue1',
            'queue1.test':'queuetest1',
            'topic1.name':'topic1',
            'topic1.test':'topic1test',
            'topic2.name':'topic2',
            'topic2.test':'topic2test',
            'ServerName': 'serverone', 
            'DeploymentName': 'deployment1'
           },

    'set2':{'fileName': 'filename2', 
            'moduleName': 'modulename2',  
            'connection1.name': 'connection1', 
            'connection1.test':'connectiontest1',
            'queue1.name': 'queue1',
            'queue1.test':'queuetest1',
            'topic1.name':'topic1',
            'topic1.test':'topic1test',
            'topic2.name':'topic2',
            'topic2.test':'topic2test',
            'ServerName': 'servertwo', 
            'DeploymentName': 'deployment2'
           }
  }
for s,setkey in a.items():
    fileName       = setkey['fileName']
    moduleName     = setkey['moduleName']
    connection     = setkey['connection1.name']
    connectiontest = setkey['connection1.test']
    topic          = setkey['topic1.name']
    topictest      = setkey['topic1.test']
    queue          = setkey['queue1.name']
    queuetest      = setkey['queue1.test']
    servername     = setkey['ServerName']
    deploymentname = setkey['DeploymentName']

    print (fileName,moduleName,                     \
                         connection,connectiontest, \
                         topic,topictest,queue,     \
                         queuetest,servername,deploymentname)

    create_server_config(fileName,moduleName,       \
                         connection,connectiontest, \
                         topic,topictest,queue,     \
                         queuetest,servername,deploymentname)

    flag = False

    if 'connection2.name' in setkey:
        flag = True
        connection     = setkey['connection2.name']
        
    if 'connection2.test' in setkey:
        flag = True
        connectiontest = setkey['connection2.test']

    if 'queue2.name'      in setkey:
        flag = True
        queue          = setkey['queue2.name']
        
    if 'queue2.test'      in setkey:
        flag = True
        queuetest      = setkey['queue2.test']

    if 'topic2.name'      in setkey:
        flag = True
        topic          = setkey['topic2.name']
        
    if 'topic2.test'      in setkey:
        flag = True
        topictest      = setkey['topic2.test']

    if flag:
        print (fileName,moduleName,                 \
                         connection,connectiontest, \
                         topic,topictest,queue,     \
                         queuetest,servername,deploymentname)

        create_server_config(fileName,moduleName,   \
                         connection,connectiontest, \
                         topic,topictest,queue,     \
                         queuetest,servername,deploymentname)
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this. Suppose if i have 10 values in queue in set1 is there simple solution. What I want is instead specifying the number connection1.test ,connection2.test , will there be any better approach